# Call a directive on ng-change of option tag in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-select

I have text any multi language accroding to their id I defined, Then create a custom directive to change according to selected language. It works fine on page load but when I change value in select tag on ng-change event, Then It convert only first element of sub select tag, not full.
This is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>Views:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select ng-model="vm.selectView" class="form-control" ng-change="vm.fillSubViews(vm.selectView)">
                    <option ng-repeat="view in viewList" value="{{view.viewId}}">
                        <div cc-text-in-lang view="view">{{view.textInCurrentSelectedLang}}</div>
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" ng-if="vm.subViews.length>0">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>Profile Views:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select ng-model="vm.selectedSubView"
                        class="form-control">
                    <option ng-repeat="view in vm.subViews" value="{{view.viewId}}">
                        <div cc-text-in-lang view="view">{{view.textInCurrentSelectedLang}}</div>
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is my directive to Show text in selected language:

```
<div cc-text-in-lang view="view">{{view.textInCurrentSelectedLang}}</div>
```

When My Page load first time, then it convert text fine, but when I change value in above select tag, then It convert only first element of below select tag, not all tag.

This is my TextinLang Directive - which convert text

Directive:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    function ccTextInLang() {
        return {
            scope: {
                view: "=",
            },
            transclude: false,
            templateUrl: "/App/Directives/TextInLang/TextInLang.html",
            controller: "textInLangCtrl as vm",
            replace: true
        };
    }

    angular.module("app")
        .directive("ccTextInLang", ccTextInLang);
})();
```

This is controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function textInLangCtrl($scope,$rootScope) {

        activate();

        function activate() {
            debugger;
            var validCaption = false;
            if ($scope.view) {
                var viewName = isJsonValid($scope.view.viewName);
                if (viewName) {
                    angular.forEach(viewName, function (item) {
                        if (item.languageCodeId === $rootScope.selectedLanguage) {
                            validCaption = true;
                            $scope.view.textInCurrentSelectedLang = item.caption;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        };

        function isJsonValid(str) {
            var validJson;
            try {
                validJson = JSON.parse(str);
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
            return validJson;
        }


    }

    textInLangCtrl.$inject = ["$scope","$rootScope"];

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("textInLangCtrl", textInLangCtrl);
})();
```

This link  is of my directive. Please take a look
[MyWindow](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nm4hjdqtghc45da/Screenshot%202016-08-11%2012.05.16.png?dl=0)

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Can you create a **working** demo like [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [plnkr](http://plnkr.co)?